# What is the meaning of "versus" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

There are phrases like "Use pipe or loop reactor vs. batch reactor vessels" and "Use continuously stirred, flow-through systems vs. batch reactor vessels."

In these cases, what is the meaning of "vs."? Does it mean we better use pipe or look reactor instead of batch reactor vessels?

Comment: in contrast to.

Comment: In your examples it seems like it could be either "in comparison to" to "in preference to". It would certainly could be clearer. "VS" is probably not the best choice of words here.

Comment: "Instead of" and "rather than" are two other options.

Comment: I am voting to close since this could have been resolved with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

*As opposed to* in this instance.